# How to get an array of Element objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, nodes, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am using a javascript plugin for gauges (http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/).

The plugin works perfectly, but I can only make it work by using (getElementById)
I want to be able to have several instances of this plugin on the same page (without repeating the code for each one), but all other javascript selectors (getElementByClass), (querySelectorAll), etc, return a list of NODE OBJECTS, instead of "ELEMENT OBJECTS" as the (getElementById) method does.

```js
var opts ={
  lines: 12,
  angle: 0.15,
  lineWidth: 0.44,
  pointer: {
    length: 0.9,
    strokeWidth: 0.035,
    color: '#000000'
  },
  limitMax: 'false',
  colorStart: '#6FADCF',
  colorStop: '#8FC0DA',
  strokeColor: '#E0E0E0',
  generateGradient: true
};

// this works
/*
var target = document.getElementById('gauge1');
var value = target.getAttribute('data-level');
var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts);
gauge.maxValue = 1000; 
gauge.animationSpeed = 32;
gauge.set(value);

*/

// this does not work
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('gauge');
for(var i=0; i<target.length; i++)
{
  var value = target[i].getAttribute('data-level');
  var gauge = new Gauge(target[i]).setOptions(opts);
  gauge.maxValue = 1000; 
  gauge.animationSpeed = 32; 
  gauge.set(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas class='gauge' id="gauge1" data-level='900'></canvas>
    <canvas class='gauge' id="gauge2" data-level='800'></canvas>
    <canvas class='gauge' id="gauge3" data-level='700'></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

So my question is:
Is there a way to get an array of "ELEMENT OBJECTS" without using Id ?

---

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is very simple and didn't have anything to do with nodes and elements.

1. I was writing "getelementbyclass" instead of "getelementbyclassname" (syntax error)
2. "value" was entered as a string into the plugin and therefore, the plugin was not correctly entered. I needed to add parseInt and it worked.

Comment: it's actually get**E**lement**sB**y**C**lass**N**ame

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can also use:

```
var target = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
```